# What's the biggest integer n that in IEEE-754 of double precision all numbers from 0 to n are represented precisely (without rounding)

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, cpu-architecture

The question is as follows (same as in the title) :

> What's the biggest integer n that in IEEE-754 of double precision all numbers from 0 to n are represented precisely (without rounding)?

I've been thinkin about it for some time now and couldn't think of the right solution. Could you help me? :)

Comment: Not a Dup. This is talking about doubles, while the other is talking about float.   There some bits of difference between the two.

Comment: @EvilTeach The answer covers doubles.

Answer (score 4):

The answer for the **largest** integer that **can** be accurately represented has already been given.

Maybe you are curious about the **smallest** integer that can **not** be represented:

> 9,007,199,254,740,993 (2^53 + 1)

It is smaller because the integers that can be represented exactly by double (binary64) are not contiguous.

Comment: @Gabe thanks Gabe, copy-paste lost the ^.

Comment: The value 9,007,199,791,611,905 is even more interesting.  That is the smallest whole number `n` such that `(float)(double)n` will not yield the `float` which is closest to `n`.